# Why are some questions coloured differently than others?

Tags: discussion, questions, design

In Stack Overflow I can see that some of the questions are shown in a different colour. What is meaning of that?

Comment: Just an OT note: English might not be your first language, but please take some time to spell things like "Stack Overflow" properly. I don't at all mind correcting the rest, but there's no need for that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you've marked the tags in that question as your favorite..

> [image: Fav]

The questions having your favorite tags appear in yellow background.

**Check the *top right* part of the page to find your favorite tags**